# Download files recursively from a directory present on unix server to local directory by ftp using Java code

Tags: java, recursion, ftp, ftp4j

I need to ftp files from a directory which has many sub-directories (and in turn each directory has many other directories and files in it) from Unix server to my local machine using Java.

I tried using `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` and `it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.FTPClient` to download, but I am unable to download files recursively.

Or is there any way to download the root directory itself to the local machine?

Please help me.

Comment: 'org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient  ' works fine. There must be something amiss in your code .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah 'org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient' works fine, but I am not able to code it properly to retrieve files recursively:(